# Isn't accessibility service not a context?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I googled and found that android service is a context. And if I want to use assets in non-activity class, I have to pass 'this' to that class. But it seems weird to me that if I pass 'this', it says that 'this' is null object reference. What should I do? I'm a noob in android studio. please help me. Is it related to accessibility service??

`my accessibility service`

```kotlin
package com.kobeazz.stopswear

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.util.Log
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent

class StopSwearingService : AccessibilityService(){
    private val swearClassifier: SwearClassifier
    private val jamo: Jamo
    companion object {
        private val TAG = "STOP_SWEARING_SERVICE"
    }

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "INIT_START")
        Log.d(TAG, this.toString())
        swearClassifier =  SwearClassifier(this)
        swearClassifier.initializeInterpreter()

        Log.d(TAG, "INIT_FINISHED")
    }

    override fun onInterrupt() {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created fun말ctions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "accessibility event called")
        if (event?.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED) {
            Log.d("TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED", event.text.toString())
        }
    }

}
```

`my class`

```kotlin
package com.kobeazz.stopswear

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.AssetManager
import android.util.Log
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel

class SwearClassifier(private val context: Context) {
    val vocabList: List<Char>
    val vocabDict: HashMap<Char, Int>
    private var interpreter: Interpreter? = null
    var isInitialized = false
        private set

    private var inputLength: Int = 0 // will be inferred from TF lite model

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "SWEAR_CLASSIFIER"
        private const val MODEL_FILE = "model.tflite"
    }

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "SwearClassifier initialized")
        vocabList = listOf('ㄷ', 'ㅏ', 'ㄴ', 'ㄱ', 'ㅜ', 'ㅎ', 'ㄹ', 'ㅇ', 'ㅂ', 'ㅓ', 'ㅈ', 'ㅣ', ' ',
                'ㅡ', 'ㅢ', 'ㅁ', 'ㅗ', 'ㅅ', 'ㅔ', 'ㅕ', 'ㅑ', ';', 'B', 'J', '.', 'P', 'G',
                'ㄸ', 'ㅟ', 'ㅃ', 'ㅌ', '[', '1', ':', '8', '2', '3', '0', ']', 'V', 'L',
                'I', 'E', 'ㅋ', 'ㅖ', '(', 'ㅠ', ')', '5', 'ㅝ', 'ㅐ', 'ㅆ', '\'', 'ㅀ', 'ㅊ',
                't', 'x', 'ㅙ', 'ㅚ', 'ㅉ', 'ㅍ', 'ㅄ', '?', 'g', 'i', 'f', 'ㅛ', '6', '7', '☀',
                'ㄲ', 'v', 's', 'ㅘ', '!', 'ㄶ', 'p', 'c', 'ㄼ', '\u3000', 'k', '4', '9', ',',
                'ㅞ', 'ㅒ', '“', '”', 'N', '‘', '’', 'T', 'O', 'a', 'r', 'm', 'S', '+', 'o', 'd',
                'l', 'u', '·', '~', '/', 'ㄻ', '^', 'ㄺ', 'e', 'n', 'A', '-', 'D', '&', 'C',
                'F', 'j', 'M', 'K', '"', '_', 'Z', 'X', 'U', '…', 'ㄾ', 'w', '=', 'z',
                '>', '<', 'b', 'H', '@', '*', 'W', 'y', 'h', 'R', '%', 'ㄽ', '．',
                'ｊ', 'ｐ', 'ｇ', 'ㄵ', '{', '}', 'q', 'Y', 'Q',
                '$', 'ㄿ', '？', 'ㆍ', 'ㄳ', '⋅', '—')
        vocabDict = HashMap<Char, Int>()
        this.vocabList.forEachIndexed {
            i, element -> vocabDict.put(element, i+1)
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "SwearClassifier initialized finished")
    }

    fun initializeInterpreter() {
        //val assetManager = context.assets
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialized TFLite interpreter.")
        val assetManager = context.assets
        val model = loadModelFile(assetManager)

        val options = Interpreter.Options()
        options.setUseNNAPI(true)
        val interpreter = Interpreter(model, options)

        val inputShape = interpreter.getInputTensor(0).shape()
        inputLength = inputShape[1]
        Log.d(TAG, inputLength.toString())

        this.interpreter = interpreter
        isInitialized = true
    }

    private fun loadModelFile(assetManager: AssetManager): ByteBuffer {
        val fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("model.tflite")
        val inputStream = FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.fileDescriptor)
        val fileChannel = inputStream.channel
        val startOffset = fileDescriptor.startOffset
        val declaredLength = fileDescriptor.declaredLength
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength)
    }

    fun classify(string: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SwearClassifier classify function is called")
        if (!isInitialized) {
            throw IllegalStateException("TF Lite interpreter is not initialized yet.")
        }
        val output = Array(1) { FloatArray(2) }
        interpreter?.run(string, output)
        getOutputString(output)
    }

    private fun getOutputString(output: Array<FloatArray>) {
        val maxIndex = output[0].indices.maxBy { output[0][it] }
        if (maxIndex == 1) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "나쁜말!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d(TAG, "나쁜말")
       }
    }

}
```

`error message`

```
2020-11-25 23:55:01.060 20471-20471/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
2020-11-25 23:55:01.061 20471-20471/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-11-25 23:55:01.075 20471-20471/? I/beazz.stopswea: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-11-25 23:55:01.095 20471-20471/? E/beazz.stopswea: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-11-25 23:55:01.102 20471-20471/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator
2020-11-25 23:55:01.102 20471-20471/? D/ActivityThread: setConscryptValidator - put
2020-11-25 23:55:01.265 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/SWEAR_CLASSIFIER: SwearClassifier initialized
2020-11-25 23:55:01.267 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/SWEAR_CLASSIFIER: SwearClassifier initialized finished
2020-11-25 23:55:01.270 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/Jamo: Jamo initialize start and finished
2020-11-25 23:55:01.270 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/STOP_SWEARING_SERVICE: INIT_START
2020-11-25 23:55:01.270 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/STOP_SWEARING_SERVICE: com.kobeazz.stopswear.StopSwearingService@9b8b9a9
2020-11-25 23:55:01.270 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/SWEAR_CLASSIFIER: Initialized TFLite interpreter.
2020-11-25 23:55:01.270 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-11-25 23:55:01.271 20471-20471/com.kobeazz.stopswear E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kobeazz.stopswear, PID: 20471
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.kobeazz.stopswear.StopSwearingService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:274)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2118)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8154)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:88)
        at com.kobeazz.stopswear.SwearClassifier.initializeInterpreter(SwearClassifier.kt:49)
        at com.kobeazz.stopswear.StopSwearingService.<init>(StopSwearingService.kt:18)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateService(AppComponentFactory.java:129)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateService(CoreComponentFactory.java:75)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4382)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:274) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2118) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8154) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Comment: It is a `Context` but you cannot use it as so inside its constructor (`init` block). You need to wait for a lifecycle method like `onCreate` to ensure framework already hooked it into base context.

Comment: @Pawel  thanks!! I forgot that important concept.